# mvvm wpf c# Entity framework tutorial

Tags: entity-framework-4, mvvm-light, mvvm-foundation, simple-mvvm

Share some good link for building application using mvvm wpf EF4 using C# .I need tutorial /video /book that that start from basic concept of mvvm using EF and C# and cover at least major topics for building a complete project/application for an enterprise.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's out there.  I looked for something similar around a year ago.  You can find tutorials on MVV, and WPF and EF, but not all together and not what you are looking for.  IMHO You are going to have to dive into a MVVM framework and learn as you go.  I used mvvm-light to start because it it "light" weight and easy to start with.  You've got a lot of reading ahead of you.

[MVVM Light Download](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)

[MVVM Light Documentation](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)

You can also look into Caliburn Micro and Prism(Microsoft)

I found this to be a bit of a learning curve so plan to take some serious time to get comfortable before dinging into an enterprise level application.  WPF done poorly has horrendous performance for the user.  But once you get it, WPF is very flexible and capable.